# Dereferencing issue in C

Tags: c, data-structures, memory-management

when I try to compile my code below I get the following errors:

error C2440: '>=' : cannot convert from 'double *' to 'double'

error C2440: '>=' : cannot convert from 'double *' to 'double'

I believe I'm dereferencing everything correctly

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0;

#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Con{
  double samTime[2];
  double sen[2];
  int test[2];
} CON, *CON_PTR;

void GM(double **TTXY) {
  int NoS;
  int numOfSen = 2;
  int startTime =0;
  CON con;

  if((con = (CON_PTR) malloc(numOfSen*sizeof(CON)))==NULL) {
    printf(“Malloc failed\n”);
    exit(1);
  }
  for (NoS=0;NoS<numOfSen;NoS++) {
    con[NoS].samTime[0] = startTime;
    con[NoS].samTime[1] = startTime;
    con[NoS].sensor[0] = 0;
    con[NoS].sensor[1] = 0;
    con[NoS].test[0] = FALSE;
    con[NoS].test[1] = FALSE;
  }

  if (con[NoS].samTime[0] >= TTXY[1]) {
    con[NoS].test[0] = TRUE;
  }
  if (con[NoS].samTime[1] == TTXY[1]) {
    con[NoS].test[1] = TRUE; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Post the actual code. There is no definition of `con` or `TTXY` in the sample you have posted. Further, the line `int NoS` is ill-formed.

Comment: #defining FALSE to contain a semicolon is a bug waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's a missing semicolon

```
int NoS
```

and your main function is not correct, this *must* be one of

```
int main()
int main(int argc, char **argv)
void main() // not standard but allowed by some compilers (with warning)
```

and as to your question, no you're not dereferencing it right, as your `TTXY` array is 2-dimensional. So it should be something like

```
if (con[NoS].samTime[0] >= TTXY[1][some other number]) {
```

whatever works for your code. And you should use more descriptive names for your variables if others are supposed to understand the code.

If `TTXY` should really be a one-dimensional array, then you don't need to pass it by reference (`function(&TTXY)`), passing the pointer value (`function(TTXY)`) will be enough and more readable.

Answer (score 1):

TTXY is declared as double **, so TTXY[1] is double *, not double, so you cannot compare TTXY[1] with con[NoS].samTime[0].

I guess may be you have a typo in function head, try modifying it to void main(double *TTXY)?

Comment: @anon I'd like to recommend that you change the function name, since using 'main' may cause ambiguity.

Comment: The _only_ standard signatures for `main` are: `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char **argv)`. `void main(double **TTXY)` will never work.

Answer (score 1):

Why does your main function have the signature

```
(int)(double**)
```

To be a valid C program, main must have the signature:

```
(int)(int, char**)
```

If you want main to process its arguments in another way, then you need to convert them on your own.

Answer (score 0):

There is four syntax errors in your program.

1. `int Nos` - missing the semicolon.
2. `con` - this variable is not declared before use.
3. `sensor` is not a memeber of `struct Con`.
4. `TTXY` is a pointer to pointer to double not point to double,so you should use `*TTXY[1]` to acess the first double point by the first double pointer in the `TTXY` double pointer array.

Note:

1. Normally you should follow the standard form of the `main` function but not defined your own version.The normal version of `main` function should be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.
2. You should include <stdlib.h> to make gcc happy enough not to give you any warnings.